# Could we display tag badges against users answers if they have any?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, answers, tag-badges

As a bit of extra information for people asking questions and future viewers, could we show any tag badges (question specific) that answering users may have against their answers?

I'm aware reputation is shown as well as the total number of badges, which is a good guide, but the tag badges show specific expertise in the tags that the question is filed under on top of the reputation.

A user may have a lot of reputation, but no specific expertise for the given tags of posts they are answering. This would add a small differentiation to highlight expertise more effectively.

Proposal would be something like this:

[image]

If an answer is edited, that space would contain the editing users information, so positioning would need some thought if the proposal is considered.

The obvious con to this is that voting probably goes some way to highlighting the better answers anyway, but we've probably all witnessed cases where the top voted answer is not always the best.

Comment: Just because a user has a gold tag badge doesn't mean the answer just posted is a good one or that it is better then an answer posted by someone who doesn't have a gold tag badge. It is just like reputation where it is not always an indicator of the quality of the answer and like reputation showing tag badges could unfairly influence how people vote on or accept answers. Not sure how showing a tag badge would improve the experience of people viewing the answer other then provide false assurances about the quality based the presence or lack of a tag badge.

Comment: @JoeW it doesn't guarantee that the answer is a good one, I agree. But I'd find it a lot more useful than the reputation, given the criteria of the badge: *a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers*.

Comment: @Stijn The problem is that if you have two answers that disagree on the solution showing a tag badge on one is likely to have a larger impact on how people view the answers then if it was just showing a high rep user and a low rep user. After all while it may not be simple it is possible to get a gold badge by answering simple questions since you just need an average score of 5 over 200 answers to get the badge.

Comment: @JoeW I agree it doesn't guarantee it will be a better answer, it's just a badge, but a gold badge in a tag isn't easily earned and it's just a way of highlight a level of expertise in the area. That was my thought process. You'd hope people would actually read the answer to make a judgement rather than just look at a badge. If anything, people may be more critical if a gold badge holder posts a bad answer or answers a low quality question that should have been closed. So it may serve more than one purpose. I've often criticized experienced users for answering instead of closing.

Comment: I also hope that the user upvoting/downvoting is looking at the answer/question quality before the rep/achievements of the poster, however, that unfortunately doesn't happen as often as one might think. All i can see this change doing is moving more of the upvotes to people with higher rep rather than people with lower rep, simply because they have more badges/rep, not necessarily because they create better content. This would give me in particular a big advantage when answering questions, one that I feel would be unfair.